# How to append text from one file to another file after a specific line using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I need to insert the contents of a text file into another existing text file after the line with a specific word in it.

Here is my code.

```
'//OPEN FILE and READ
Set objFileToRead = fso.OpenTextFile(ActiveDocument.Path & "\file.txt", 1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close

objStartFolder = ActiveDocument.Path
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.files

For Each objFile In colFiles
  If fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "opf" Then
    filename = objFile.Name
  End If
Next
MsgBox filename

'///PASTE
If fso.FileExists(ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & filename) Then
  MsgBox filename
  Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & filename)

  Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    If InStr(strLine, "<manifest>") = 1 Then
      MsgBox filename
      objFile.WriteLine vbCrLf & strFileText
      objFile.Close
    End If
  Loop
End If
```

I get a bad file error in the following line

```
objFile.WriteLine vbCrLf & strFileText
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong and what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write to a file that was opened for reading.

Either write the modified content to a temporary file and replace the original file with it afterwards:

```
p = fso.BuildPathActiveDocument.Path, filename)

Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(p)
Set f2 = fso.OpenTextFile(p & ".tmp", 2, True)

Do Until f1.AtEndOfStream
  line = f1.ReadLine
  f2.WriteLine line
  If InStr(line, "<manifest>") = 1 Then f2.WriteLine strFileText
Loop

f1.Close
f2.Close

fso.DeleteFile p, True
fso.GetFile(p & ".tmp").Name = filename
```

or read the entire content into memory before writing the modified content back to the original file:

```
p = fso.BuildPathActiveDocument.Path, filename)

txt = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(p).ReadAll, vbNewLine)

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(p, 2)
For Each line In original
  f.WriteLine line
  If InStr(line, "<manifest>") = 1 Then f.WriteLine strFileText
Next
f.Close
```

Note that the latter shouldn't be used for large files, lest your computer come grinding to a halt due to memory exhaustion.

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers.

Comment: But I have a doubt, Is the code used to modify a single file or will it copy content from one file and append it to different file

Comment: Both snippets modify the source file, because that's what the code from your question attempted to do. If you want to write to a different file: use the first snippet, pick an appropriate name for the output file, and drop the part that replaces the original file.